# Issues with XML Layout and Software Buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

So basically I have an activity with 4 buttons that in Android Studio look out of the way of the software buttons at the bottom of the screen but when I run it on my phone they are not. I'm not sure if I have the right constraints on the bottom button or not?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewMainMenu"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="258dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: What the app looks like in Android Studio]

[image: This is what the app looks like on my phone]

Comment: post your `xml` code

Comment: @AbuYousuf I've updated the post with the XML code

Answer (score 0):

if you use from ConstraintLayout, you can add this attribute:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

by this code, your view sticks on bottom of layout.

and for other views you can use from this code:

```
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/{bottom View}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are explicitly setting the button heights and the top button's top margin to fixed values. On your device, the total sum of all the heights and the padding exceed the height of the device.

An easy fix is to *not* constrain the top of the topmost button to the parent and remove the top margin. Then it will lay above the button below it but won't push down from the top of the parent.

Generally speaking, you should avoid fixed-size widths and height for this exact reason. You can leverage things like *weighted chains* in ConstraintLayout to size things proportionally instead of explicitly.

See the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) docs for more.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are wrong. You have used both `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` constraints which is wrong. Use only  `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` constraint to stack one above other. 
Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NewMainMenu"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"


    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]some codes is not right
please write below codes:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```